# Backend JSON To HTML for Front End

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, web-frontend

We have a product like `Zillow` which has all the Active Properties for Sale. We have a spring boot backend that has JSON Rest API to get those Properties that are on Sale.

Our simple front end calls this JSON API and renders the properties for our HomeBuyers.

The problem is anyone can steal our listings and build their website in minutes from our JSON API. So here is what we would like to do. Instead of JSON we would like to send a HTML to FrontEnd. Our problem is how to go about it in most modern/scalabale efficient way..

Some Options:

1) Don't open our JSON APIs to internet but Write another JAVA Service that fronts the JSON API service and translates them to HTML. So our front end calls upon this new JAVA service and not directly the JSON API service..

2) Node JS App which in Backend talks to JSON API and Converts it to HTML while the front end talks to this Node App.. (Are there any libraries that already do this? Have you ever used them)

Any help/options/opinions you provide are greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You can "secure" your JSON api with an authentification method like JSON Webtokens. That way, nobody who isn't authenticated can use the JSON api. Use Google's Angular JS to render to your website.

Comment: I don't think JWT solves what the OP is asking. JWT only authenticate the messages, but the OP wants to protect the API for scraping. Which I think it's not really possible(at least not easily).